# c program to check digits in number are even

Tags: c, digits

Input and Output Format:

Input consists of a number which corresponds to the bill number.
bill number is a 3-digit number and all the 3 digits in the number are even.

Output consists of a string that is either 'yes' or 'no'. Output is yes when the customer receives the prize and is no otherwise.

Samples:

```
Input     Output
565       no
620       yes
66        no         # Not a 3-digit number (implicit leading zeros not allowed)
002       yes        # 3-digit number
```

I have solved the problem by getting single digit with "number" mod 10 and then  checking if "digit" mod 2 is 0 or not......

But in case if I give input "002", it prints "no" instead I want it should be "yes".

Code — copied and formatted from comment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int num, t, flag, count = 0;
    while (num)
    {
        t = num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
        if (t % 2 == 0)
        {
            flag = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            flag = 0;
        }
        count++;
    }
    if (flag == 1 && count == 3)
    {
        printf("yes");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("no");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @SharptechCompany: How sure are you that this code is working? You are not even considering the input from the user for `num`.

Comment: Please edit your code into your question in future.  I've done it for you this time (formatted the way I prefer, more or less — if you prefer a different format, please reformat it to suit yourself).  Where do you initialize `num`?  Short answer: you don't.  You can't run the code and supply different values.  Don't miss out crucial code.  You probably need to read a string and analyze the string; otherwise, you won't be able to spot leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

You have to work with strings instead of numbers, otherwise you cannot represent the `002` value.

Recognize even digits:

```
int even(char c) {
    switch (c) {
        case '0':
        case '2':
        case '4':
        case '6':
        case '8':
            return 1;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Recognize strings with only even digits:

```
int all_even(char* s) {
    while (*s != '\0') {
        if (!even(*s)) {
            return 0;
        }
        s++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Return "yes" only for strings of 3 even digits, and return "no" for all other strings:

```
char* answer(char* s) {
    return (strlen(s) == 3 && all_even(s)) ? "yes" : "no";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How can you read 002 in integer? When you enter 002, value of `num` will be `2` only not `002`. In this case you `while loop` will run for one time only and value of `count` will be `1`. So you `if` condition is `false` in this case.

Try this solution.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 void main(){
    char bill[4];
    int i, flag=0;
    int digit, len;

    scanf("%s",bill);

    len = strlen(bill);
    if(len<3){
            printf("no\n");
            return;
    }

    for(i=0;i<len;i++){

            digit = bill[i] - '0';

            if(digit%2 == 0) flag = 1;
            else{
                    flag = 0;
                    break;
            }
    }

    if(i==3 && flag == 1) printf("Yes\n");
    else printf("No\n");

    return;
}
```

Comment: In case of your suggestion if i'll give input of any one digit like "1","2"..etc it will give "yes"...but i want "no" for a single digit and same for two digit number. Output should "yes" only if input is  3 digits and all of three should even.

Comment: Then try to read this `bill number` as `char array` and then you can do it.

Here is sample code for it.

`
char bill[4];
int len;
int digit;
int i, flag=0;
scanf(“%s”,bill);

len = strlen(bill);
if(len < 3){
 printf(“No\n”);
 return;
}

for(i=0;i<len;i++){

 digit = arr[0] - ‘0’;
 if(digit%2) flag = 1
 else{
  flag = 0;
  break;
 }
}

if(flag==1 && i==3) printf(“Yes\n”);
else printf(“No\n”);
`

Comment: it is giving output "yes" for input as "002" but for "032" its giving "yes" too but 3 is odd digit in the number

Comment: Note that this will report 'yes' (it is an even number) if you type 2467.  That's because the `scanf()` stops after three non-blank characters.

Comment: Yes Right, But @SharptechCompany has mentioned that bill number contains 3 digit. User can enter more then 3 digit. Developer needs to handle all this senior.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    char * checknum(char a)
    {
        switch (a){
            case '0':
            case '2':
            case '4':
            case '8':
            return "YES";
            default: return "NO";
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        char input [3];int i;
        char * output;
        printf("Enter the number");
        scanf("%s",&input);
        if(strlen(input)==3)
        {
            for(i=0;i<strlen(input);i++)
            {
                output=checknum(input[i]);
                if(output=="NO")
                {
                    printf("NO\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(output=="YES")
                {
                    printf("YES\n");
                }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: i tried the above code but it is giving      Compilation Errors -
 warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]
Main.c:115:14: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]

Comment: I am testing this code on below link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php

Comment: You compare strings with `strcmp()`.  The use of `"YES"` and `"NO"` in the check function is unexpected.  It would be better to call the function `is_even_digit()` and have it return 0 (false) if not and 1 (true) if so.  I note that if the user types `fluffy` instead of a number, the code would treat that as a sequence of odd digits — the letters of the alphabet are very odd digits indeed, of course.